# Three circles implies incenter

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

> Let $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ be two circles with centers $C_1$ and
>   $C_2$, respectively, which intersect at two points $P$ and $Q$.
>   Suppose that the circumcircle of triangle $PC_1C_2$ intersects
>   $\omega_1$ at $A \neq P$ and $\omega_2$ at $B \neq P$. Suppose further
>   that $Q$ is inside the triangle $PAB$. Show that $Q$ is the incenter
>   of triangle $PAB$.

How would the adaptation or a new solution of the question posed by the link provide a similar one?

**Question [ China TST 2002 Quiz 6 P2] :** $ \odot O_1$ and $ \odot O_2$ meet at points $ P$ and $ Q$. The circle through $ P$, $ O_1$ and $ O_2$ meets $ \odot O_1$ and $ \odot O_2$ at points $ A$ and $ B$. Prove that the distance from $ Q$ to the lines $ PA$, $ PB$ and $ AB$ are equal.

(Prove the following three cases: $ O_1$ and $ O_2$ are in the common space of $ \odot O_1$ and $ \odot O_2$; $ O_1$ and $ O_2$ are out of the common space of $ \odot O_1$ and $ \odot O_2$; $ O_1$ is in the common space of $ \odot O_1$ and $ \odot O_2$, $ O_2$ is out of the common space of $ \odot O_1$ and $ \odot O_2$

**Solution:** This one is quite easy compared to the other China TST problems.
Note that $\triangle O_1PO_2\cong\triangle O_1QO_2\implies \angle O_2O_1P=\angle O_2O_1B.$ Also, $\angle PO_1O_2=\angle PAO_2,$ and $\angle QO_1O_2=\angle BAO_2,$ leading to $\angle PAQ=\angle BAQ.$
So $AQ$ bisects $\angle PAB.$ Similarly $BQ$ bisects $\angle PBA,$ so $Q$ is the incentre of $\triangle PAB.$
So it is equidistant from $PA,PB$ and $AB.\Box$

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something in the solution, why is $O_1 QB$ a straight line?

Comment: @CalvinLin $O_1PO_2B$ is a cyclic quad.

Comment: This is problem 1 from the [2019 Brazilian National Olympiad](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1952359p13478932).

Comment: @user574848 Here is the real proof file  https://www.obm.org.br/content/uploads/2019/11/Prova_Nivel_3_OBM_2019.pdf